# Accessing IPython 3.0 notebook metadata in nbconvert

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I need to access notebooks metadata specified in the ipynb file inside a template to create correct markdown text. How can one generally access notebook's JSON formatted metadata in the templates?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask